# After clicking on table tr, how can I display this data on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, click

This is my code for a website that displays videos from a MySQL database. 'videoRef' is the YouTube embed code that is stored in a video table.

```
$result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM videos")
or die( mysqli_error($link) );

echo "<table border=0><tr><th>Title</th><th>Creator</th><th>Upload Date</th><th >Difficulty</th><th>Video</th></tr>";

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $data['Title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data['Creator'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data['Upload Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data['Difficulty'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . '<iframe width="350" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.($data['videoRef']).'" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>' . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I would like to make it so that when a row is clicked, it will redirect to another page and start playing the respective video but the video dimensions are larger. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

The possible solutions:

1. Include link with embed wideo with large dimensions:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$data['videoRef']><iframe>...</iframe></a>
```

2. Include usual link to video:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$data['videoRef']><iframe>...</iframe></a>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, I don't have a problem with the videos themselves but more of how I would actually display them on another page. Like how when you search a video on YouTube, a list of videos comes up, but when you click on one it redirects to new page and it is larger. Thanks.